# I Have to need ajax data in two functions in my controller

Tags: javascript, php

```
private function _make_active_row($data) {
    return array(($data['user']),
                ($data['uptime']),
                (format_bytes($data['rx-byte'], 2)),
                (format_bytes($data['tx-byte'], 2)),
                ($data['remote-address']),
                ( modal_anchor(get_uri("clients/online_bandwidth"), "<i data-feather='tablet' class='icon-16'></i>", 
                array(  "class" => "edit", 
                        "title" => app_lang('clients_current_session_details'),  
                        "data-post-id" => ($data['.id'])
                )
            )
        )
    ); 
}  

          
function online_details() { 
    $this->access_only_allowed_members();           
    return $this->template->view("clients/online_details"); 
}
      
public function online_bandwidth() {
    $this->template->view("clients/online_details");
    $this->access_only_allowed_members();          
    $API = new Mikweb();    
    $API->connect('192.168.88.6', 'shyriad', 'shyriad#1332');           
    $interface = $this->request->getPost('id');

    $getinterfacetraffic = $API->comm("/interface/monitor-traffic",  array("interface" => "$interface", "once" => " "));              
    $rows = array(); 
    $rows2 = array();
    $ftx = $getinterfacetraffic[0]['tx-bits-per-second'];
    $frx = $getinterfacetraffic[0]['rx-bits-per-second'];
    $rows['name'] = 'Tx';
    $rows['data'][] = $ftx;
    $rows2['name'] = 'Rx';
    $rows2['data'][] = $frx;
    
    $result = array();
    
    array_push($result,$rows);
    array_push($result,$rows2);             
    print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
}
```

i have two functions in a controller.

Now i am received ajax data into $online_bandwidth. But i have to received ajax data in two functions a the same time. With modal_anchor click. Because one of my function load the template and other function loads the highchart data. please help me.

Comment: The miriad of unnecessary `(` and `)` do nothing but make that code almost unreadable

Comment: i have not understand your answer. Please write in details .

Comment: I was just commenting on how unreadable the code was, I have no idea what your question is about

Comment: My problem is i cannot load template file with result. when i use return $this->template->view("clients/online_details"); my chart is stops moving. But my result are shown in outside of the template. https://prnt.sc/w1p1xTEAqS3p